# Hook into theme-switching later than `setup_theme`

Tags: plugin-development, themes, hooks

I need to add a theme-switching logic to a site. Unfortunately, what I've tried already doesn't seem to work as required.

The themes needs to switch based on whether the user is on the blog part of the site (e.g. `is_single()`, `is_category()`, `get_post_type() == 'post'`), versus any other section (e.g. `is_shop()`, `is_page()`, etc.)

Unfortunately, having created a plugin to do this, it appears that none of these conditionals are available at the only point I can feasibly hook in: `setup_theme`.

With the following:

```
function vnmFunctionality_getTheme() {

    $isBlog = (is_author() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_date() || is_home() || is_single()) && 'post' == get_post_type();

    if ($isBlog) {
        return 'blog-theme';
    } else {
        return 'site-theme';
    }
}

function vnmFunctionality_conditionalThemeSwitch() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    add_filter('template', 'vnmFunctionality_getTheme');
    add_filter('stylesheet', 'vnmFunctionality_getTheme');
}

add_action('setup_theme', 'vnmFunctionality_conditionalThemeSwitch', 100);
```

This *works* (insofar as there are no errors), but `$isBlog` will always return false because none of those conditionals are available at `setup_theme`. If I don't use `add_action('setup_theme')` and instead move the `add_filter` lines to the root of the plugin, the conditionals *are* available, but it causes a host of other issues (for example, the `blog-theme` seems to try to act like a messed-up quasi-child of `site-theme`, and fails to load everything that's enqueued in `site-theme`'s functions file).

I also tried looking at the `global $wp_query` object to see if I could figure out where you are on the site, but even that seems to be empty at `setup_theme`.

I can't seem to hook in any later than `setup_theme` for the theme-switching to work properly, but that seems too early to be able to figure out where the user actually is on the site. Is there a way of achieving this?

*For reference: The need is based on requirements outside of my influence (read: client). This secondary 'blog-only' theme is fundamentally different from the rest of the site (and was produced by another developer), so unfortunately integrating it into the existing theme isn't feasible.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the blog part of the site has a different url-structure (eg `www.example.com/blog/this-is-my-blogpost`) you can use the PHP [`$_SERVER`](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-php.php) variable to determine which page is being called and use that in an expression to make `$isBlog` true at the appropriate moment.